# Pros/Cons of common robotics "kits" at the high school level

Tags: raspberry-pi, mindstorms, kit, children

I am interested in starting a robotics club at my high school next year, since we don't have one, and I want to know what the pros/cons are of common kits. I already have a Vex kit since my uncle is one of the regional suppliers for Indiana, but I'm not sure that Vex is the best choice. What are the pros/cons of the other kits out there?

Note: I looked at Lego Mindstorms, and have used them when I was learning robotics, but do not want them for this. Also, i own a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I'm sorry *PythonInProgress* but making your request for opinions **louder** does not make it any less *opinion based*. In order to answer questions effectively they need to be [*practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face*](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Lists of products go out of date quickly, personal opinions on what is best change and there are so many schools out there that no-one can say what is *most common*. Asking [***how** to choose*](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1132/37) is a much better option, and that's been done.

Comment: @MarkBooth sorry , i dont think "common" is an opinion... :P Is there any way to make this a legitimate question? I though my original one would be ok....

Comment: @MarkBooth i changed the question a bit. Better?

Comment: Thanks for trying to to make this more answerable *PythonInProgress*, but I'm afraid that it's still essentially asking for a *list*, and this sort of question is rarely useful to future visitors. I would suggest asking a new question, based on specific issues that you have identified with the answers on the question this is closed as a duplicate of.

Comment: @MarkBooth thanks... could i just edit this question with those answers?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, sorry.

Comment: @MarkBooth thanks anyhow :D see you on other SE sites (im mostly stackoverflow and Gamedev)